# Запуск дополнительных утилит в ходе работы программы

Tags: grep, c++

Возможен ли запуск дополнительных утилит в ходе работы программы? К примеру, для работы моей программы необходимо обработать большой файл с данными. Что лучше сделать, запустить `grep` отдельным процессом, и каким либо образом получить данные с выхода (каким именно мне пока не понятно) или скомпилировать какую-либо библиотеку реализующую ф-л `grep`'а?

Answer (score 1):

Запуск утилит, конечно, возможен. Именно так поступают многие GUI-программы. Что лучше - выбирайте сами. Если скорость работы и расход памяти не так принципиальны, а важнее надежность и скорость разработки, можно запустить другое приложение и считать его вывод. Если же нужно, чтобы все работало быстро, лучше либо самому написать соответственный код или использовать уже имеющиеся библиотеки, просто подключив их. Можно посмотреть существующие приложения, как так реализован требуемый функционал.

Считывать вывод дочернего процесса можно либо используя функцию popen(), либо низкоуровнево - системные вызовы pipe и dup2.